# Accessing a class object using a Function and With / End With

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a class object `classBlock` which uses an array to speed up read/writes to an Excel sheet. I've also created a function to make it easy to use:

```
Function funcBlock(objSheet as WorkSheet) as classBlock
    Set funcBlock = New classBlock
    funcBlock.Initialize objSheet
End Function
```

If I call the function using a `With` construct as follows...

```
With funcBlock(ActiveSheet)
    .SomeFunctions
End With
```

... does an instance of `classBlock` exist after the `End With`?

If I call `funcBlock` multiple times, am I cluttering memory with instances of `classBlock`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say No and Yes. The latter might depend upon the class destructor. However, if you used a variant array on a large block of cells to assist processing, you would not keep rereading the cell values into the array; no, you would bulk load the values once, process them, then bulk dump them back onto teh worksheet. I fail to see why you would need to repeatedly call your class, With... End With or not.

Comment: Thanks. In the project I'm working on, I'll probably call it three or four times, on different ranges and on different sheets. I could probably restructure the code so that it's only called once per sheet, but at this stage I'm just trying to understand what happens to the class instance in the above scenario.

Comment: Add a terminate event to your class so you can see when precisely it is destroyed. However, your class will be reinstantiated when you start a new With block, because the function instantiates a new copy of the class each time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you missunderstand the concept of `With-End With`?
*The [With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx) statement allows you to perform a series of statements on a specified object without requalifying the name of the object.*

So you get the instance of the class and then the `With` can be used to write statements without having to repeat the object name:

```
Dim block as classBlock
Set block = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)

With block
    .SomeFunctions
    ' .SomeProperty = 100
    ' .Save(true)
    ' etc.
End With
```

The `With` only saves you from typing the following.

```
block.SomeFunctions
block.SomeProperty = 100
block.Save(true)
```

The instance of the class is now referenced by the variable `block` and it exists according to the scope where it was declared.

If you call the function `funcBlock` multiple times you will create new object each time you called the function.

So lets call the function e.g. three times:

```
Dim block1 as classBlock
Set block1 = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)

Dim block2 as classBlock
Set block2 = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)

Dim block3 as classBlock
Set block3 = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)
```

Now you have three objects in memory which are referenced with the variables `block1, block2, block3`.
With this variables the objects can be accessed.

But when you call the function `funcBlock` three times like this:

```
Dim block as classBlock
Set block = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)

' some code ...
Set block = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)

' some code ...
Set block = funcBlock(ActiveSheet)
```

... then only the last instance is referenced by the varaible `block` and can be accessed.
The first two instances just clutter the memory :). HTH

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. Following **jkpieterse**'s suggestion, I added the following to `classBlock`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox "HELLO"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    MsgBox "GOODBYE"
End Sub
```

I then ran the following:

```
Sub Test

    With funcBlock(ActiveSheet)
    End With

    MsgBox "AFTER"

End Sub
```

The resultant message sequence is: `HELLO`, `GOODBYE`, `AFTER`. This implies to me that Excel is recognising that the instance was created at the `With` and so destroys it at the `End With`. Presumably the array created by `classBlock` is also erased when the class instance is destroyed.

Comment: Well this is interesting, maybe I misunderstood your question :).

Comment: No problem. Like you, I was concerned about cluttering memory with redundant class instances, but it looks like Excel manages it well.